# Реферральная система

Tags: mysql

Нужно выбрать количество приглашенных первого и второго уровня.

Получаем количество приглашенных первого уровня

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ref WHERE referrer = @id
```

Второго уровня

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ref WHERE referrer IN (SELECT referral FROM ref WHERE referrer = @id);
```

Можно ли это все сделать одним запросом?
Можно ли как то ускорить при том что у одного пользователя может быть приглашенных первого уровня > 25000?

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| referrer  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| referral  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_time | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: *Можно ли это все сделать одним запросом?* Да, конечно, можно. *Можно ли как то ускорить* Да Вы сперва хоть как-то получите, потом будете думать об ускорении.

Comment: Опечатка. Исправил.

Comment: Получите рефералов 2 уровня - данные на них полностью. А потом `COUNT(*)+COUNT(DISTINCT referrer)`.